# help on left outer join with parent-child relationship

Tags: oracle, plsql, outer-join

i have following table in my database :

```
id   grp#  code  parent#
--   ----  ----  -------
 0     10  US       NULL     
 0     30  SF         10 
 1     10  S        NULL 
 1     30  SF         10
```

From this, given an id and grp# i need to return the list of children and the code for the grp#. If the children doesn't exist it should return NULL.

So for example : for id = 0, grp#= 10 it should return US, 30 and for id = 0, grp#=30 it should return SF,NULL

Note : there should not be duplicates in the output.

Comment: You need to elaborate more.  I've read this question and your examples several times and still don't know what u are asking.  What is "list of children"?  What defines a child in this?

Comment: grp# and parent# follow child - parent relationship. 10 is the parent of 30 i.e., 30 is the child of 10. so if we query for id = 0 and grp# = 10 we need to return 30 and US. If we query for id = 0 and grp#= 30 we need to return NULL and SF.

Answer (score 2):

So here is your test data:

```
SQL> select * from t42
  2  /

        ID       GRP# CODE                    PARENT#
---------- ---------- -------------------- ----------
         0         10 US
         0         30 SF                           10
         1         10 S
         1         30 SF                           10

SQL>
```

And here is a query which returns the results you want:

```
SQL> select p.code
  2         , c.grp# as child_grp#
  3  from t42 p
  4       left outer join t42 c
  5        on ( c.parent# = p.grp# )
  6  where p.id = &id
  7  and p.grp# = &grp
  8  /
Enter value for id: 0
old   6: where p.id = &id
new   6: where p.id = 0
Enter value for grp: 10
old   7: and p.grp# = &grp
new   7: and p.grp# = 10

CODE                 CHILD_GRP#
-------------------- ----------
US                           30
US                           30

SQL> r
  1  select p.code
  2         , c.grp# as child_grp#
  3  from t42 p
  4       left outer join t42 c
  5        on ( c.parent# = p.grp# )
  6  where p.id = &id
  7* and p.grp# = &grp
Enter value for id: 0
old   6: where p.id = &id
new   6: where p.id = 0
Enter value for grp: 30
old   7: and p.grp# = &grp
new   7: and p.grp# = 30

CODE                 CHILD_GRP#
-------------------- ----------
SF

SQL>
```

---

> "Can we rewrite the query to return a single row instead of
>   duplicates ?"

Certainly - provided you can specify the additional business rule.

The easy way out is to deploy the DISTINCT keyword, the last resort of the broken query.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. But as you can see in the first query you are getting the output twice. That is happening because of the join and the c.id being 1 for the second row. I don't want that. Can we rewrite the query to return a single row instead of duplicates ?

Comment: It looks to me like the join condition should be 2 columns instead of just one.   Like    on ( c.parent# = p.grp# and c.id = p.id)

Comment: @ToddPierce - that would be my guess too, but we shouldn't have to guess.  The question ought to have all the relevant details.

Comment: @Todd, using your join condition will fail for the case when the input is 30. I want SF, NULL where as your query may return NULL as o/p.

Comment: can you please let me know if there is further info that is needed here ? My requirement is simple, I need the tuple code, list of children given a grp# without any duplicates. Thanks.